# R: loop with dplyr

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have multiple objects with names `depth_*`
I want to summarize them like that:

```
depth_PATH2 %>%
+   summarise(avg = mean(V3), sd = sd(V3), med = median(V3))
```

which gives:

```
  avg sd med
1   1  0   1
```

But I'd link to run a loop over all those files so that I would get a giant table like:

```
             avg sd med
depth_PATH2   1   0  1
depth_PGTH7   2   7  3
etc.
```

Can you help?
Thanks!

M

Comment: [Put them in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `mget` from base R to make a list of your `data.frame`s.

Then you can then `bind_rows` to make them into one `data.frame`, `group_by` the object, and summarize.

```
library(dplyr)
mget(ls(pattern="depth_")) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "obj") %>%
  group_by(obj) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(V3), sd = sd(V3), med = median(V3))
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#  obj       avg    sd   med
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 depth_a   2    0      2  
#2 depth_b   4.5  2.12   4.5
#3 depth_c   6    4.24   6
```

**Sample Data**

```
depth_a <- data.frame(A = c(1,2), V3 = c(2,2))
depth_b <- data.frame(A = c(1,2), V3 = c(6,3))
depth_c <- data.frame(A = c(1,2), V3 = c(9,3))
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ian, it's working well and is easy enough to remember ahah!